# Spring JpaRepositort return selected pojo fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity containing 30 fields.

Currently I use `PagingAndSortingRepository` to provide `findAll` and `findAllBy`... rest  filtering services.  This returns all 30 fields.

I have a requirement to return only selected fields.

for example, user select `field1`, `field5`, `field11`, `field25` and the service should return a json containing these 4 fields only.

I would appreciate any suggestion or an example on how to do this. The easiest I can think of is to create the query on the fly, but in this case, the `PagingAndSortingRepository` interface can't see it.

I need to maintain the paging and sorting capability.

Comment: Are you exposing your `PagingAndSortingRepository` instances directly as @RestController, or is there a layer in between? And are you returning the entities themselves from the @RestController or an intermediate representation?

Comment: I have a Service(interface) and serviceImpl in between.   The controller calls the service impl which in turn calls the repo.

Comment: The PagingAndSortingRepository returns a Page to the service which get passed back to the controller.   The page is a list of the full Pojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed set solution:**

In case you have predefined combination property-sets (eg. combine `field1`, `field3` and `field20` for one usecase and return `field4` and `field8` for another usecase) you can get away with annotating your POJO's with multiple `@JsonView` annotations (see http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation for good explanation).

Depending on the set of fields you need, you can use the right view in your controller, based on the 'set' the user requested.

**Dynamic set solution 1:**
In case you actually want ANY random combination (not known in advance) of fields to be returned by the resource, the JsonView won't cut it.

You can, instead, add a custom `BeanPropertyWriter` or custom serializer that just skips (doens't call the `jsonGen.writeXXX`) for the properties that were not requested. The difficulty here is to get the requested properties (which are passed in to your REST controller) to be known in the writer/serializer, which is called by Spring's Jackson message converter. Not 100% sure how this might work, but this will allow you to use the same POJO.

**Dynamic set solution 2:**

A bit more tedious: you can use your `commons-beanutils` to convert the POJO to a `Map`, instead of just returning the POJO from the controller. This way, you'll have a flattened representation of your POJO. Next, you can just remove the keys from the map, which are not part of the 'requested fields' list and return the Map (or List/Page) and let Jackon to it's magic on that.

This will result in the same JSON as would be generated by the POJO itself, if you're not using advanced JSON* annotations I guess...

This can be applied to any type of Object so extracting this behaviour in a base-resource or something whould hide the heavy lifting a bit.

Comment: I ended up using a different approach than suggested due to number of fields in the POJO and the large number of potential request combination.  After the full json comes back from JpaRepo call, I used json exclude to remove unwanted fields before sending to the view.   This seems to work fine.